# Angular ng-click not working with $compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

I have code similar to the below code to trigger a `click` event in an Angular app. Why is not the event triggering?

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])

app.directive('myTop',function($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div></div>',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, element) {
        var childElement = '<button ng-click="clickFunc()">CLICK</button>';
        element.append(childElement);
        $compile(childElement)(scope);

        scope.clickFunc = function () {
            alert('Hello, world!');
        };
    }
}
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your compile statement like this:

```
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

You were passing a DOM string `childElement` which is really not a DOM element instead it is a string. But the `$compile` needs the DOM element(s) to actually compile the content.

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);

app.directive('myTop', ['$compile',
  function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div></div>',
      replace: true,
      link: function(scope, element) {
        var childElement = '<button ng-click="clickFunc()">CLICK</button>';
        element.append(childElement);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);

        scope.clickFunc = function() {
          alert('Hello, world!');
        };
      }
    }
  }
])
```

```html
<html>

<body ng-app="myapp">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <my-top></my-top>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you read the usage documentation for `$compile`, you'll see it accepts a string. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#usage